# LibreOffice Calc Custom Function with arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am trying to write a custom function in LibreOffice Calc that has an arbitrary number of arguments. Does anyone have an idea if that's possible? An example:

`Function sum_custom(a,b,c)
    sum_custom = a+b+c;
End Function`

Is it possible to extend this function so it can take an arbitrary number of arguments?

PS: It is not about the actual sum, it is about the number of arguments..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Excel VBA this is possible using the ParamArray: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/538f81ec.aspx.

At least with the last versions of Libreoffice the ParamArray can also be used if `Option Compatible` is set.

Example:

```
Option Compatible

public function sum_custom(ParamArray arr_args() as Variant) as Double
 sum_custom = 0
 for i = lbound(arr_args) to ubound(arr_args) 
  sum_custom = sum_custom + arr_args(i)
 next
end function
```

Can be used as

`=SUM_CUSTOM(1;2;3)`

or

`=SUM_CUSTOM(A1;A2;A3;A4)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ATM, I think I will give it a try the next weekend. Currently, I expanded my function so that it can take many arguments (which is sufficient for my problem). Still, this is not a generic solutions that makes me happy.

Comment: Using `Option Compatible` may also not really increase the happiness ;-) because it may have side effects. So to use as much optional parameters as maximally needed may really be the best solution. But give it a try.